# Batch file to replace TABs with a comma ","

Tags: batch-file, text-processing

Can anyone please help me find a batch file script that automatically removes `TAB` characters and replaces them with `,` ?

For example:

```
61  LEUKOCELL 2                     7737    PK25    278 N   Y
97  SNAP COMBO PLUS (FELV/FIV)      9906034 PK15    290.82  N   Y
```

I have 90k+ lines of this in text files: can I automate the reformatting with a batch file to this:

```
61,LEUKOCELL 2,7737,PK25,278,N,Y
97,SNAP COMBO PLUS (FELV/FIV),906034,PK15,90.82,N,Y
```

Comment: Does this need to be a Windows `.bat` file, or can you use something like Python or Perl?

Comment: You could try dbenham's [JREPL.bat](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044&sid=7c4cc72f296bb6c6400fc9ea1a3669ae), a batch/jscript hybrid. It should work on any current windows system without additional installations

Comment: @Will Windows `.bat` file , anyone has a clue? I hope you can help me guys

Comment: @jeb Ehh, I'm really beginner in programming/scripting and stuff.. I looked at your given link, it wasn't quite understandable :D Thx anyway

Comment: Is all the text within a .txt file or something similar?

Comment: You aren't replacing all space with a comma - some spaces aren't replaced.  How can we tell which are which?

Comment: That will be a tricky because you don't really want to replace ALL of the spaces... looks like at least the spaces in the second field need to remain. Are you sure those are spaces? Might they be tabs?

Comment: Yes, the file is txt. Here's the screenshot how it looks like. [link](http://imgur.com/7ruYSwr)

Comment: @RGuggisberg Yes, they are Tabs, sorry. I just need to seperate ALL the tabs by with comma. like example

Comment: @foxidrive These are tabs, I need a batch code to automatically sort the tabs seperated by comma. for example 61,LEUKOCELL 2,7337,PK25,278,N,Y instead of 61  LEUKOCELL 2                     7737    PK25    278 N   Y

Comment: Actually I can pay something symbolic who can help me with this, really need this guys :/

Comment: Its more/less impossible as far as I'm aware bacause you don't want to replace all the spaces with comma, just some. It is possible however to do something with all of the spaces.

Comment: @MadsTheMan Yes, I already found a way to just put the commas in all the spaces. But I really want to know if there's a way just to seperate these tabs with comma.

Comment: Why do you have a value `290.82` in the original file (2nd line) but a value of `90.82` in the modified one? is that a typo?

Comment: If you really want to replace all _TABs_ by `,` as you stated [above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34875733/batch-file-that-replaces-90k-lines-spaces-with-commas#comment57491824_34875733), then use something like this in a loop: `%VAR_LINE: =,%` (there is a _TAB_ in that command line, not a _SPACE_, of course);

Answer (score 2):

You don't need complicated methods to achieve a replacement as simple as this one. The small Batch file below replace all Tabs with comma:

```
@set @a=0  /*
@cscript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0" < input.txt > output.txt
@move /Y output.txt input.txt
@goto :EOF */

WScript.Stdout.Write(WScript.StdIn.ReadAll().replace(/\t/g,","));
```

Save this code with .BAT extension.

Comment: It needs the global switch too, Antonio, as it only replaces the first match.

Comment: Perfect, thank you guys. Umm, one more thing. Can the final action can be done as transforming this txt to `.csv` file? The thing is, this `.txt` file is made originally from `.csv` file. It needs to be comma delimited and saved as `.csv`? Is this possible guys? :)

Comment: Humm... Using `< input.txt > output.csv`?

Comment: @Aacini, he started another question on the code you gave him. You are replacing all of the tabs with commas but he wants all of the data to show up in Column A when you open it up with Excel.  Which means each line would also need to be quote surrounded.

Comment: This is how it should look in the final result, with this batch file - [link](http://imgur.com/ExMq3IZ)

Comment: I don't understand you. This solution generate the output _exactly as requested_ in the question. Do you want to _change the specifications_ of this question? In such a case, I need a _clear description_ of the new output. "The output should look like this image" is _NOT_ a specification! **`:/`** I have not excell, so I have no idea what you are talking about...

Comment: this simply works! awesome! and to convert txt file to csv, another simple solution is -- type input.txt > output.csv

Answer (score 1):

This should replace all TABS with a comma.

```
call jrepl "\t" "," /x /f "input-file.txt" /o "output-file.txt"
```

This uses a native Windows batch script called `Jrepl.bat` written by dbenham that uses `jscript` to make it very robust and swift.
http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044

Place it in the same folder as the batch file, or in a folder that is on the system path.

There is also copy on Dropbox (unblock it after downloading):
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4otci4d4s8x5ni4/Jrepl.bat

Comment: Hi foxidrive, thanks. But what should I place in the same folder? how and what? I just see a long script there, but where should I copy it ?

Comment: The command I showed above is to go in a separate batch script, or on the command line.  Put `jrepl.bat` in the same folder or in a folder on the path.

Comment: Did as you said, window popped for 0.5 seconds and that's it, nothing else happened :( Screenshot - [link](http://imgur.com/RKVRshi)

Comment: The `input webfile.txt` needs to be changed to `webfile.txt`

Comment: Beauty.  Tell dbenham that he's a wizard. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q34875733.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"
(
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 SET "line=%%a"&call :process
)

)>"%outfile%"
GOTO :EOF

:process
SET /a "col1=%line:~0,4%"
SET "col2=%line:~4,32%"
SET "col2=%col2:                =%"
SET "col2=%col2:        =%"
SET "col2=%col2:    =%"
SET "col2=%col2:  =%"
IF "%col2:~-1%"==" " SET "col2=%col2:~0,-1%"
FOR /f "tokens=1-5" %%i IN ("%line:~36%") DO ECHO %col1%,%col2%,%%i,%%j,%%k,%%l,%%m

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q34875733.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Produces the file defined as %outfile%

Assuming your layout is fixed-column as described and that there are no characters in the data to which batch shows sensitivity, repeating your 2 lines to a file with 90K+ lines had a run-time of about 7 minutes on my machine.

For each line, assign the line to `line` and process by

- selecting the first 4 columns as a number to `col1`
- selecting the next 32 columns to `col2`
- replacing strings of 16,8,4 and 2 spaces by a *nothing*
- removing the last character, if it is a space
- tokenising the part of the line after the column using default separators and building the output line.

---

Replacement routine

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q34875733.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"
SET "tab=   "
(
FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1-7delims=%tab%" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 REM detect missing column 3
 IF "%%g" == "" (ECHO %%a,%%b,,%%c,%%d,%%e,%%f) ELSE (ECHO %%a,%%b,%%c,%%d,%%e,%%f,%%g)
)

)>"%outfile%"
GOTO :EOF
```

Having looked at your source data, it would apper that the columns are aligned using tabs and column 3 is sometimes missing (413 denelan)

Hence - replacement routine (you'd need to reformat the source data 61 LEUKOCELL 2 to the same format as it would appear you use for the rest of the file.

Note that the character between the quotes in the setting of the variable `tab` is a <kbd>Tab</kbd> not a string of spaces.

So this time, break the line into 7 columns using tab (or sequence of tabs) as separators; assign to %%a..%%g and regurgitate. If column 3 is missing, `%%g` will nt be assigned (since there is one column short) so `%%g` will appear to be *nothing*. If this situation is detected, insert an empty field as column 3 (hence `,,`)

I've assumed that all of the data contains either 7 columns or 6 columns where column 3 is missing.

Comment: Magoo, perfect, I almost solved my big problem. But the thing is, it somehow gives me a little bit inaccurate data and it doesn't do what I need for all the lines, just for some. Here's the screenshot of what I got and your code I used. Please tell me what's wrong? Screenshot - [link](http://imgur.com/0fRBnQX)

Comment: You got my idea perfectly Magoo, can you please help me understand how to fix these issues to get all the file working(im really beginner in coding) and for the commas which are still displaced.? Screenshot - [link](http://imgur.com/Rtt20sE)   Thanks Magoo!!!

Comment: Thanks Magoo, I tried your replacement - Still something not right, this is what I got this time - Screenshot [link](http://imgur.com/ampohsO)

Comment: Thanks for your effort Magoo, brilliant support you are. I got it working.!

Comment: You need to replace the character between the `=` and the closing quote `"`in the `set tab=...` line with a bona-fide tab character. If it's a space (or series of spaces) then you'll get the result you've reported.

Comment: Thankyou Magoo, ur best. Umm, one more thing. Can the final action can be done as transforming this txt to `.csv` file? The thing is, this `.txt` file is made originally from `.csv` file. It needs to be comma delimited and saved as `.csv`? Is this possible guys? :)

Comment: A .csv file is simply a text file with an extension of .csv instead of .txt By convention, .csv contains comma-separated values. Spreadsheet programs can normally import data from any filename provided the internal structure follows csv conventions - and not necessarily using commas as separators, either. The enemy here is tabs. Using tabs sets the text-format to be visually in-columns, typewriter-style. Consequently, a short data field (483) may contain multiple tabs to align the next field visually, but csv conbention with tab-separators makes this a series of empty fields.